# SQL Query - SELECT WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table2.Var = @Var

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create an SQL query for an ASP NET drop down list using two tables and a session variable.

I want to retrieve the all values from table 1 which correspond to a matching ids in table 2, where table 2 is filtered by an external variable.

As it is clear I do not know how to word this question, here is a simplified example of what I am attempting to do:

- My site has a session variable which holds the current colour the user is "filtering".
- A dropdown list will show a list of cars corresponding to that colour using an SQL query.

For example if the session variable was "Blue" the dropdown list would contain "Punto" as it can see that the colour ID for "Blue" is 12 and "Punto" is the only car name corresponding to that colour.

Linked image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zT90.png

[image]

As session variables can be assigned and called in ASP NET custom queries the session variable can just be referred to as, for example, @ExternalVar (Colours.ID WHERE (Colours.Name = @ExternalVar))

Apologies I had to word this like a quiz question; giving a simplified example was the only way I could really articulate my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do the trick if I understand the question above

```
select * from Cars c
inner join Colours cl  on c.colourID = cl.ID
where cl.Name = @ExternalVar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Cars.* FROM Colours 
INNER JOIN Cars 
ON Colours.ID = Cars.ColourID
WHERE Colours.Name = @Variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using SQL Joins. Use below sql query:-

Declare @ExternalVar VARCHAR(50) = 'Blue'

```
Select C.Name FROM Cars C INNER JOIN Colours CO ON CO.ID = C.ColourId WHERE CO.Name = @ExternalVar
```